# Opening of fragments from listfragment

Tags: android-listfragment

I am new to `android programming`. I have created a listview fragment that work perfectly. I want on the the click of an item in the list to open the selected fragment. I have the following errors.  Can anybody please help. I have an error on `showFragment(position)`;

```
"can't resolve symbol 'position' and on
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content.f).commit();
    viewActionsContentView.showContent(); "can't resolve symbol on       "getSupportFragmentManager and viewActionContentView"
```

here is my **listview coding**

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content.f).commit();
    viewActionsContentView.showContent();
```